# Get i18n locale as global variable in all pages in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization

I want to get the locale as a global variable in any component of my app without using any other external libraries.

I have json files for translations `en.js` and `es.js`:

`es.js`

```js
export default {
  home: 'Inicio',
  signin: 'Iniciar Sesion',
  welcome: 'Bienvenido',
};
```

I have already set `next.config.js`:

```js
i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    defaultLocale: 'es',
  },
```

And I can get the locale in any component by `router.locale`:

`home.js`

```js
import en from "../lib/i18n/en";
import es from "../lib/i18n/es";

const HomePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { locale } = router;
  const t = locale === 'en' ? en : es;
  return (
    <div>t.home</div>
  )
}
```

All good, the question is, how can I replicate this in all the components without having to call the router all the time and replicating the logic to get `t`. A solution that would allow me something like this:

`home.js`

```js
import t from "../lib/i18n/t";

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>t.home</div>
  )
}
```

Making `t` a global variable or that all the components have the context to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it generally different:

```js
//localized.js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export const words = {
  login: {
    de: 'Login',
    en: 'Login',
  },
  register: {
    de: 'Register',
    en: 'Registrieren',
  },
  includeUpdate: {
    de: 'Update Link anhängen.',
    en: 'Include update link.',
  },
  // ......
}

export default function t(text) {
  const { locale } = useRouter();

  return text?.[locale] || text;
}
```

Nor you can use it like so:

```js
import {words, t} from 'path/to/localized.js'

cont Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>{t(words.login)}</div>
    <div>{t({de: "Ein anderer Text.", en: "Some other text."})}</div>
  )
}
```